# Asking about thesis papers which I don't understand

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I have faced so many problems understanding the topics of some thesis papers or publications when I am reading them. I'm trying to implement code based on the ideas.

Here in Stack Overflow we discuss code and algorithms, but trying to understand a thesis paper which will help you to research further in a field may be a different thing. The papers do not always contain many references for algorithm or code; they provide the very basic idea on the topic.

I'll provide links to the papers when asking. May I ask here for help understanding these papers, or this is a bad idea?

Comment: What is the thesis about?

Comment: The thesis is about "Segmantation of hanwritten text document" @Mat

Comment: Stackoverflow is more for programming questions, perhaps you should pinpoint the information in the papers. Most likely it's going to be something dealing with Computer Science, and you can ask/find CS questions at the [CS stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely ask about stuff you've read that you don't understand on Stack Overflow. The determining factor is whether the topic fits.

Stack Overflow is by and large about *coding*: sitting at the keyboard, writing a program. For higher-level "whiteboard" subjects, there's [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

I would say that there is likely to be a better site [in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for your question, as you've described it, than Stack Overflow.

You should have a look at [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) to see if you can figure out where that might be.